# Permanently registering colormaps in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently have a large set of colormaps that I have used in other languages that I would like to import into python for use in matplotlib.  I am able to convert a three column ascii file to an RGB array, then to a colormap like so:

```
def from_ascii(filename, name):
    palette = open(filename)
    lines = palette.readlines()
    carray = np.zeros([len(lines), 3])
    for num, line in enumerate(lines):
        carray[num, :] = [float(val) for val in line.strip().split()]
    cmap = colors.ListedColormap(carray, name=name)
```

I can then register that colormap:

```
cm.register_cmap(name=name, cmap=cmap)
```

so that:

```
In [4]: cm.get_cmap('my_cmap')
Out[4]: <matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap instance at 0x1b114c68>
```

The problem is that `cm.get_cmap()` only is able to retrieve my custom colormap if I am in the same program.  As soon as I attempt to call for my custom colormap from a separate script, `cm.get_cmap()` returns None.

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the colormap to exist between sessions, you'll have to save the code in a file and import it each time you need it.  You can do this automatically for interactive sessions via the .pythonrc in your home directory.  For scripts, you'll need to make it explicit, or edit the matplotlib code.

Comment: Ah, I guess I had assumed there was a way to permanently register the colormap so that the code that generated it wouldn't ever have to be run again.  Darn, for what I'm doing that makes things a little more difficult.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

pickle saved a cmap to file for me and loaded it later. Here's my code, copied straight out of the example for pickle in the python docs:

```
    import pickle
    fp = open('cmap.pkl', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(self.myPanel.cmap_n, fp)
    fp.close()
```

and later...

```
    import pickle
    fp = open('cmap.pkl', 'rb')
    last_cmap = pickle.load(fp)
    fp.close()
```

Comment: Ah, pickle is a good solution.  I'm not sure why that didn't cross my mind when I was working on this.  I wound up using ascii files, but have gotten this handled relatively cleanly at this point.  I think I may revisit this and try using pickle, though.  Is the actual cmap instance serializable?

Comment: Pickle is not a good solution, you should never open a pickle you did not write your self.